# Gettin NaN value instead of integer

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown list and I'm passing the value to a function which performs a task when the value changes.

```
<li style="background-color:white; float:right">
  <select id="dpItems" onchange='loadScript();'>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option> 
  </select> items per page
</li>
```

And the javascript that is getting the value as follows:

```
function loadScript() {
  var newItems = parseInt($("#dpItems").val());
  alert('New value: ' + newItems);
  console.log('New value: ' + newItems);
}
```

But I'm always getting NaN value instead of the correct value on the option within the select. I tried changing the value on the option to 5 (without quotes) but same result.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The HTML calls "loadScript" but the function you posted is "updateItems()". How are they related?

Comment: My bad, the function is calling loadScript but when pasting I changed, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass its value to the onchange function and it will not be undefined:

```
<select id="dpItems" onchange='loadScript(this.value);'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert `undefined` into an integer.

```
Number.isNaN(parseInt(undefined)) === true;
```

Comment: Why it is undefined, I'm checking for the val, is not correct?

Comment: @CarlosM `$("#dpItems").val()` is yielding `undefined`. You might have more than one select with id `dpItems`.